# Is there a way to convert a .CED (EEGLAB channel location) file to txt for loading in python?

Tags: python, mne-python

I have a .CED file which is an EEGLAB channel location file for EEG data. I want to convert this file to a txt file and access it using python. How do i do that so the 'mne' library in python can access it?

I have tried to change the file extension to .txt. However the data gets corrupted if i do that.